How can I connect to a MariaDB database in Rust (on W10)?
Diesel seems to be a popular crate for database connections. So that's what I tried first. But the question is (now) accurately expressed: I am interested in any way of connecting between Rust and MariaDB, on W10.
I've been following these "getting started" instructions. I got as far as making (and re-doing) the migrations. As explained there, this automatically creates a file "schema.rs", which in my case looks like this:
diesel::table! {
    posts (id) {
        id -> Unsigned<Integer>,
        #[max_length = 50]
        title -> Varchar,
        body -> Text,
        published -> Bit,
    }
}

My up.sql file, in order to be valid MariaDB SQL, is like this:
CREATE TABLE posts (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  body TEXT NOT NULL,
  published BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

However, when I then try to run the first cargo run command, namely cargo run --bin show_posts, I get the following error:
error: failed to run custom build command for `mysqlclient-sys v0.3.1`
...
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `D:/apps/rust/auto_generated/diesel_demo/target\debug\build\mysqlclient-sys-c22c8c5dcbc4ae83\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo::rerun-if-env-changed=MYSQLCLIENT_VERSION
  cargo::rerun-if-env-changed=MYSQLCLIENT_LIB
  ... # about 50 more lines like this
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at D:\apps\rust\rust_1.70.0\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\mysqlclient-sys-0.3.1\build.rs:77:5:
  Did not find a compatible version of libmysqlclient.
  Ensure that you installed one and teached mysqlclient-sys how to find it
  You have the following options for that:
  ...

NB "compatible version of libmysqlclient".
Can someone explain what I need to do at this point? I believe I'm getting this because I'm trying to use Rust designed for MySQL with MariaDB, but it could be another reason. My research seems to show that MariaDB instead has a "dbase connector" (which I have installed, and use with Python). It seems that this is its equivalent to libmysqlclient. But again I could be completely wrong.
But it appears that the Diesel crate, with the "mysql" feature, requires the presence of "libmysqlclient". Does anyone know whether using MariaDB is still possible? Or is this doomed to fail? Can any Rust database crate work with MariaDB?

Rust: version 1.78
Mariadb: version "mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)"

Do you have the "mysql" Diesel feature enabled?

@kmdreko Thanks! I have created this same test crate a few times this afternoon. This time I forgot to change from "postgres" to "mysql". Trying again ...

@kmdreko Yes, changing that has moved me forward. But I have encountered another problem, to do with "libmysqlclient". Editing question.

Diesel does not have anything specific for MariaDB. However, MariaDB advertises it self as (mostly) compatible with MySQL. From MariaDB's compatibility page:

MariaDB's client protocol is binary compatible with MySQL's client protocol.

Though as seen further down the page there are still quite a few incompatibilities and the list keeps growing as new versions are released.

Either way, to use MariaDB with Diesel, you will just set up everything as if you are connecting to a MySQL database. For this you need:

to enable the "mysql" feature:
diesel = { version = "2.2.0", features = ["mysql"] }


to link with a MySQL client:
Diesel uses the mysqlclient-sys crate for linking and its installation instructions are thus:

For this crate to build, libmysqlclient must be installed on your system (brew install mysql on macOS, apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev on Ubuntu, included with the server distribution on Windows). Additionally, either pkg-config or mysql_config must be present and able to successfully locate libmysqlclient.

Even if you have a MariaDB client installed, your Diesel-based Rust application will use the MySQL client.

Use diesel::mysql types.


Beyond that, you may encounter problems if/when you try to use MariaDB-specific syntax through Diesel - who would reject the structure as non-MySQL. For those cases you may need to reach for a raw sql_query or maybe a custom operator  (defined in Diesel via prefix_operator!, infix_operator!, postfix_operator!, or similar).

Thanks. Yes, it's not looking too promising, but I'll see what I can do. As I say, I'm on Windows, and thus this component is "included with the server distribution on Windows", i.e. the MySQL server. Which I don't have. I can of course install MySQL for that sole purpose and see if I can achieve something that way. A dedicated "MariaDB-Rust" crate seems lacking from my searches so far, unfortunately.

@mikerodent From reading down the mysqlclient-sys page, it should be using vcpkg to install libmysql automatically. So you could try some of those commands yourself and/or adjust some environment variables to get it working. Otherwise I would suggest perusing or opening an issue.

Afterthought: I have local ODBC connections set up for some of my MariaDB databases. I wonder if that offers a way forward? My knowledge of databases is about as basic as that of Rust, but I'll try that too. Oh, in fact: https://crates.io/crates/odbc-api "tested against ... MariaDB". Helpful.

I don't think Diesel has any ODBC support and I don't see any third-party Diesel backend for it either.

Oh, sure: I've no attachment to Diesel. I'm just going to see whether that ODBC crate can offer some basic way of linking to my databases. Or not at all (I have no idea).

To add on top what is already written here: mysqlclient-sys does totally support linking to libmariadb: https://github.com/sgrif/mysqlclient-sys/blob/4026e260399d236b9adbbde9b82d16ab3edafdab/build.rs#L34
You just happen to use a operating system that provides no way to query which library is installed, so you need to configure that on your own.

@weiznich Thanks for providing that clarification. But it opens a can of worms. 1) installing MySQL might well mess up badly my existing MariaDB installation: I have memories of the efforts it took to rid my system of all traces of MySQL. 2) this obviously involves setting up some environment variables: where are the instructions for that? This has every appearance of being a far from trivial task, especially installing only those bits and pieces needed, and not letting MySQL actually install itself with a fully-fledged installation.

Not to mention kmdreko's caveats about MariaDB syntax having now become significantly incompatible with MySQL. I think this calls for a new issue at Diesel's github site: "please can you implement MariaDB-compatible arrangements?". Will do that.

@weiznich Ah... so you're one of the "guiding minds" behind Diesel. I see this question of MariaDB compatible arrangements was discussed in 2023-03, issue 1882. To quote yourself "Be warned that this requires likely a complex large change to diesel itself." Any thoughts about this?

Just to leave a comment here as well: 1) Just because someone opens an issue in the issue tracker that does not mean that anything will happen. 2) Your local setup problems are really just local setup problems. These are not related to whether or not MariaDB is supported by diesel, as they are not about the database at all, just about your choice of the client library.

You have several options there: 1. Use the mysqlclient library that works as well with MariaDB (eg. via the bundling support), 2 Use pgk-config. 3 figure out a way to get it working with the mariadb client (you are on your own there due to your choice for not using any of the other supported variants).
